# power shell script to get drive space ( percentage used and free )

Tags: shell, powershell, command-line, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to get DISK SPACE (Windows) in Percentage used and free.

Script from which I get the space,

```
 get-psdrive | where Free*
```

Comment: This sounds more like a 3rd grade math problem than a programming problem. What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Logicaldisk -ComputerName localhost |  
where {($_.DriveType -eq 3 -or $_.DriveType -eq 2) -and $_.FileSystem -ne $null } |  
Select -Property 
@{Name = 'Volume';Expression = {$_.DeviceID -replace ":",""}}, 
@{Name = 'Free';Expression = { "{0:N0}%" -f (($_.FreeSpace/$_.Size) * 100) } }
```