# PowerShell - Why is an array used in this line of code, please?

Tags: powershell

I have the following code that looks for a string in multiple files, part of which I found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1372892/find-all-files-and-lines-that-contains-a-specific-string/1373006).

```
$path = C:\Windows
Set-Location -path $path

$searchWords = 'log.txt'

Foreach ($sw in $searchWords)
{
    Get-Childitem -Path $path -Recurse -include "*.txt","*.dll" | 
    Select-String -Pattern "$sw" | 
    Select Path,LineNumber,@{n='SearchWord';e={$sw}}
}
```

The syntax I don't think I understand is this part in the last line:

```
@{n='SearchWord';e={$sw}}
```

I'll explain what I think I understand and then ask questions.

1. @ I think means it is an array
2. n= is shorthand for 'name'
3. the colon(;) is separating the name of the column and the expression that fills the column.
4. e= is shorthand for expression
5. {$sw} - the brackets are necessary here to encapsulate the expression.

Question(s):

1. Why is an array used to populate this column?
2. Why must an expression be used and not just the variable '$sw'?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are looking at [Calculated Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1#example-10--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not an array but hash table. In the quoted code, a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1) is used. Usually calculated properties are used to, well, calculate stuff. For example, free disk space can be calculated as percents as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39960420/503046):

```
@{Name = 'Free';Expression = { "{0:N0}%" -f (($_.FreeSpace/$_.Size) * 100) } }
```

In the sample you used, calculated property is used to add a label property that contains the search term used on each iteration of the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone.  I didn't know what a calculated property was.  @vonPryz helped me understand this.  For others trying to understand calculated properties, here are some links which further explain Calculated Properties.

Adam Bertram: [Using PowerShell's Calculated Properties](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/01/19/using-powershell-calculated-properties.aspx)

Microsoft Documentation: [Calculated Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1)